# Need to figure out what FKs point to a specific table

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQLServer 2008 r2.  I need to figure for a specific table what FK's in other tables point to it.

I try:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

But this does not give me what I need.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the management views:

`sys.foreign_keys`

and

`sys.foreign_key_columns`

The latter one has column and object IDs for both sides of the constraint, so you can do a query like:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(Constraint_object_id) as 'ConstraintTable',
       c1.name,
       OBJECT_NAME(Parent_object_id) 'ParentTable',
       c2.name
FROM Sys.foreign_key_columns fk
INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
  ON c1.column_id = fk.constraint_column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c2
  ON c2.column_id = fk.parent_column_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it may get you what you need:

http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Programmatically-picking-apart-foreign-key-constraints.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181942/15401) is to a database reverse engineering script that I wrote a few years ago.  Amongst other things it has a query that reverse engineers foreign keys.  You may be able to get what you want by adapting it.